# AeroGear: How to send silent push notification with AeroGear to iOS using AeroGear UnifiedPush Server?

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, aerogear

I created silent push notifications with Pusher that works with that JSON:

```
{
    "aps" : {
        "content-available" : 1
    },
    "acme1" : "bar",
    "acme2" : 42
}
```

What is important here is the content-available to 1 to get it.

My problem now, is to use it in AeroGear UnifiedPush Server & Docker, but when I construct my JSON, I cannot put that keys.

I tried this without success:

```
curl -u "c94ab6da-17e1-4c35-b17f-1ab482152a65:57781ef0-9105-440d-b902-217461c0e743"     -v -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-type: application/json"     -X POST  -d   '{
     "message": {
      "alert": "Hello from the curl HTTP Sender!","content-available": true  
     }}'     http://localhost:18081/rest/sender
```

It returns me an error:

```
Unrecognized field &quot;content-available&quot; (class org.jboss.aerogear.unifiedpush.message.Message), not marked as ignorable
```

[Documentation](https://aerogear.org/docs/unifiedpush/push-message-format/)
How to send Push Notifications in iOS with AeroGear UnifiedPush Server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add **apns** object to your JSON. A complete message sample is as follow :

```js
{
  "message": {
    "alert": "HELLO!",
    "sound": "default",
    "badge": 2,
    "consolidationKey": null,
    "priority": "normal",
    "windows": {
      "type": "tile",
      "duration": null,
      "badge": null,
      "tileType": "TileWideBlockAndText01",
      "toastType": null,
      "images": [
      ],
      "textFields": [
      ],
      "page": "/MainPage.xaml"
    },
    "apns": {
      "title": null,
      "action": null,
      "action-category": "some value",
      "url-args": null,
      "content-available": true,
      "mutable-content": false,
      "localized-key": null,
      "localized-arguments": null,
      "localized-title-key": null,
      "localized-title-arguments": null
    },

    "user-data": {
      "key2": "other value",
      "key": "value"
    },
    "simple-push": "version=123"
  },
  "criteria": {
    "categories": [
      "someCategories"
    ],
    "variants": [
      "someVariantIDs"
    ],
    "alias": [
      "someUsername"
    ],
    "deviceType": [
      "someDevice"
    ]
  },
  "config": {
    "ttl": 3360
  }
}
```

You can test it with your **curl** command.